# Issue to run query in Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get data from a MySQL database using query in Java. The same query is working perfectly in MySQL, but shows error while trying it in Java.

Error says:

> sqlGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

#### Java code

This code is written on EmployeeRepository to search uid on the bases of EmployeeId as employee and user are joined with each other using OneToOne join.

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{
    @Query(value = "SELECT e.dob, e.name, e.marital FROM employee e\n" +
                    "JOIN empuser eu ON e.empid = eu.empid \n" +
                    "JOIN user u ON u.uid = eu.empid WHERE u.uid = = :uid", nativeQuery = true)
    public Employee findEmployeeByUid(@Param("uid") long uid);
}
```

##### Employee entity class

This code is of Employee entity which have joins with different entity to make a employee complete.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="empid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
    long empId;
    String name;
    Date dob;
    char gender;
    String marital;
    String nationality;
    String photoFile;
    
    //joining employee with address
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="tempaddress",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="aid")
    )
    Address tempAddress;
    
    //joining employee with address
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="permaaddress",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="aid")
    )
    Address permaAddress;
    
    //joining employee with contact
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="empcontact",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="cid")
    )
    List <Contact> EmpContact;
    
    //joining employee with familydetail
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="empfamilydetail",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="fid")
    )
    FamilyDetail EmpFamilyDetail;
    
    //joining employee with Health
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="emphealth",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="hid")
    )
    Health EmpHealth;
    
    //joining employee with OfficeDetail
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="empofficedetail",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="oid")
    )
    OfficeDetail EmpOfficeDetail;
    
    //joining employee with team
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="empteam",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="tid")
    )
    Set <Team> empteam;
    
    //joining employee with IdentityDocuments
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="empidentitydocuments",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="iid")
    )
    List <IdentityDocuments> EmpIdentityDocuments;
    
    
    //joining employee with education 
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
            @JoinTable(
                    name="empdetails",
                    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="empid"),
                    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="eid")
                )
    List<Education> empDetails;
    
    //joining employee with role
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
            @JoinTable
            (
                    name="emprole",
                    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empid"),
                    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="rid")
            )
    Role EmpRole;
    
    //joining employee with user
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="empuser",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="uid")
    )
    User EmpUser;
    
    //Joining Employee with Attendance
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="empattendance",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="attenid")
    )
    List<Attendance> EmpAttendance;

    //Joining Employee with LeaveUsed
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="empleaveused",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="lusedid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="leaveid")
    )
    List<LeaveUsed> EmpLeaveUsed;
```

##### User entity class

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="user")
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="uid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long uid;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Date lastLogin;
    
    //joining user with role
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable
    (
            name="user_role",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="uid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="rid")
    )
    Role user_role;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are using native query. If you are using complex native query in that case you have to explicitly convert the result set form list of array of objects.

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{
@Query(value = "SELECT e.dob, e.name, e.marital FROM employee e\n" +
                "JOIN empuser eu ON e.empid = eu.empid \n" +
                "JOIN user u ON u.uid = eu.empid WHERE u.uid = = :uid", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> findEmployeeByUid(@Param("uid") long uid);
}
```

Not the resultset is store in the Object[] array and you have to write mapping code for it.

```
List<Object[]> res = myRepo.findEmployeeByUid(123);
for(Object[] obj : res)
String someValue = String.valueOf(obj["COLUMN_NAME"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically your JPA method signature would be `List<Employee>`, rather than just `Employee`.  But, as you are using a native query, the return type should be `List<Object[]>`, so use this version:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT e.dob, e.name, e.marital FROM employee e\n" +
                   "JOIN empuser eu ON e.empid = eu.empid \n" +
                   "JOIN user u ON u.uid = eu.empid WHERE u.uid = = :uid", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Object[]> findEmployeeByUid(@Param("uid") long uid);
}
```

When accessing the various components inside each `Object[]` in the above list, you'll need to do some manual marshalling.  For example, to access the employee name:

```java
List<Object[]> employees = employeeRepository.findEmployeeByUid(123L);
for (Object[] emp : employees) {
    String name = (String)emp[1];
}
```

Native queries often require such unattractive code, so I would suggest trying to express your query using pure JPA if possible.